# MVC3: Razor Validation Text: Make red without setting validation message to null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This works fine:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Definition)
```

except for the fact that the text comes out black. I want it in red. So, I tried this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Definition, null, new { style = "color: red" })
```

However, that is setting the message to NULL. It's crazy that there is no overload that will take the htmlAttributes arg without the message arg..... argghhh!!!

What's the most elegant way to accomplish this (without me having to write my own validation messages)?

Comment: Have you tried it? Because if you're passing a `null` message using that overload, the final message won't be null, it will show up as intended.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934713/show-email-validation-message-in-red-in-mvc-razor

Answered There.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2011/05/12/asp.net-mvc3-change-validation-class.aspx

**EDIT**

Answer now here: http://jstawski.com/post/2011/05/13/ASPNET-MVC3-change-validation-class

Basically:

If you are using the ASP.net MVC3 built in validation such as

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)
```

you can easily change the validation by overriding the CSS class field-validation-error like this:

```
.field-validation-error
{
    color: red;
}

.validation-summary-errors
{
    color: Red;
}
```

Comment: The answer is no longer there. please briefly describe the solution and then add the link.